# Modify sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

Is it possible to add a colored font to a word in sublime text editor 3 for example lets say I have this(using the language python):

```
if 2 > 4: return False
```

All `if`, `return`, and `True` are color coded now if I do:

```
verdict = False
if 2 > 4: return verdict
```

Verdict isn't color coded though. Is there a way to edit sublime to have it place a colored font on verdict?

Comment: Do you just want to color the word `verdict`, or all values of `return`?

Comment: Variables generally are not color coded. What exactly do you have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

1. Close Sublime Text
2. Go to `\Sublime Text 3\Packages\`
3. Open `Python.sublime-package` as zip file (or rename to .zip)
4. Open `Python.tmLanguage` as text file
5. Find line 34 and add this `<dict>`

   ```
   <key>patterns</key>
   <array>
       <dict>
           <key>match</key>
           <string>\b(verdict|Verdict)\b</string>
           <key>name</key>
           <string>constant.language.python</string>
       </dict>
   ```

This mean that the keywords `verdict` and `Verdict` will be displayed with the style of constants. You can add as much keywords as you want, however, it will not work dynamically. You can tweak the `<string>` value to have the word displayed with different style.